# ¿Comó expandir tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo un tableview con celdas que se extienden de acuerdo con el contenido de la celda. Lo que trato de hacer es cuando se cargue la informacion en **CellForRowAt IndexPath** tenga el tamaño de la altura del label que está en la celda más las constraints para que al momento de seleccionar la celda en **didSelectRowAt indexPath** pueda expandir la celda al tamaño total para que se pueda ver todo su contenido.

Espero poder ocultar el texto para que cuando hagan clic en la celda, se haga lo de expandir

[image: Espero poder ocultar el texto para que cuando hagan clic en la celda, se haga lo de expandir]

Lo que he tratado de hacer es que **HeightFotRowAt IndexPath** es obtener la celda acutal y las medidas que comenté en el parrafo anterior pero lo anterior regresa un menasje

> [Assert] Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view
> while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is
> not allowed. Make a symbolic breakpoint at
> UITableViewAlertForCellForRowAtIndexPathAccessDuringUpdate to catch
> this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur. Perhaps you
> are trying to ask the table view for a cell from inside a table view
> callback about a specific row? Table view

De acuerdo con lo que ví cuando en **cellForForAt IndexPath** cuando llega a la parte de ***dequeueReusableCell*** se va al método **HeightFotRowAt IndexPath** y no entra donde obtengo la info de la celda, despuès regresa a **cellForForAt IndexPath** y termina de ejecutarse.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView === MainTable{
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MedName", for: indexPath) as? MedCell{
                
                let backgroundView              =  UIView()
                backgroundView.backgroundColor  =  UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
                cell.selectedBackgroundView     =  backgroundView
                
                let index                       =  indexPath.row
                cell.setMedName(name: self.medCatalog[index].nombre,
                                uso: self.medCatalog[index].uso )
                
                
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if let cell =  tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MedCell {

        let nameHeight             =  cell.medText.bounds.height
        let topAnchor: CGFloat     =  12.0
        let bottomAnchor: CGFloat  =  10.0

        let cellHeight             =  nameHeight + topAnchor + bottomAnchor
        print(cellHeight)

        return cellHeight
        
    }
    return 85
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El warning es muy claro, no puedes acceder al row que recién se está dibujando en esta línea en el método `heightForRowAt`:

```
if let cell =  tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MedCell {
```

Puedes intentar esto:
Declara estos diccionarios en donde vas a almacenar un `bool` que te diga si es la celda que necesitas y en la otra el valor del `bounds` del `text` de la celda

```
var cellsH: [Int:CGFloat] = [:]
var cellB: [Int:Bool] = [:]
```

Cuando creas la celda agregas los valores a esos diccionarios:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView === MainTable{
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MedName", for: indexPath) as? MedCell{
                
                let backgroundView              =  UIView()
                backgroundView.backgroundColor  =  UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
                cell.selectedBackgroundView     =  backgroundView
                
                let index                       =  indexPath.row
                cell.setMedName(name: self.medCatalog[index].nombre,
                                uso: self.medCatalog[index].uso )
                
                //Aquí agregas los valores
                self.cellB[indexPath.row] = true
                self.cellsH[indexPath.row] = cell.medText.bounds.height

                return cell
            }
        }
        self.cellB[indexPath.row] = false
        self.cellsH[indexPath.row] = 0.0
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Ahora al momento de modificar el `height` trabajas con los valores de esos diccionarios en la posición del `indexPath.row`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if self.cellB[indexPath.row] != nil {
        if self.cellB[indexPath.row]! {
            let nameHeight             =  self.cellH[indexPath.row]!
            let topAnchor: CGFloat     =  12.0
            let bottomAnchor: CGFloat  =  10.0

            let cellHeight             =  nameHeight + topAnchor + bottomAnchor
            print(cellHeight)
            return cellHeight
        }
    }
        
    return 85
}
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, pero primero se ejecuta **cellForForAt IndexPath** completo y después **heightForRowAt indexPath** o como es el orden de ejecución?

Comment: Sería `cellForRow` y luego `heightForRowAt` por cada celda. Así el manejo de memoria es óptimo y más rápido la carga.